# Insert record into oracle after defining virtual column

Tags: oracle

So I noticed that after defining a virtual column in oracle I wasn't able to insert without mentioning specific column name. Is there any documentation about this?

eg:- Without defining a Virtual Column, the following works:

```
INSERT INTO film VALUES ('12F', 'Full Screen', 2015);
```

However, once I define a virtual column called number (which stores the number part from number_key) like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE film ADD (number AS (substr(number_key,1,2)));
```

I am unable to add the records using the above insert statement, I get an error:

```
 SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
 00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
```

I have to explicitly qualify the column names in my insert queries. Why is that the case? Am I mising something here.

Comment: Always name the columns - even in the absence of virtual columns, your code will fail (or worse, silently insert bad data) as soon as it is run when the columns happened to have been added to the table in a different order.

Comment: Actually, in the case of adding new columns, the statement would fail for the same reasons "not enough values".

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be an expectation that we should qualify the column names for inserts. More information ca be found [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=510).

Comment: I wouldn't call something that makes you follow best practices something that "doesn't make sense".

Comment: I found this is a good source for using virtual columns: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=510

Comment: Thanks, Ankit. You save my time.